# Component in Talend to upload a file to server that returns code other than 200

Tags: java, talend

In Talend Data Integration I need to upload a file (with multipart/form-data) to http server. Server in response returns http code other than **200 OK** - for example **201 Created**, **202 Accepted**.

I tried to use **tFileFetch** but this component only accepts responses with a code 200.

Is in Talend any component that during file upload can handle http status code other than 200?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by writing a custom component. I copied source from **tFileFetch** and then I modified it to fulfill my requirements.

I followed tutorial found at: http://www.talendbyexample.com/talend-custom-component-writing-overview.html